# svelteKit 2 Failed to deployed on vercel

Tags: vercel, sveltekit

I recently migrated my application to svelteKit 2 and svelte4. I rectified everything locally and everything worked perfectly. But deploying to vercel results in the following error. Help me resolve, please.[vercel log screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn287.jpg)

I Ask help on discord svelte commununity but,it's not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your @sveltejs/adapter-auto package is updated to the latest version that supports sveltekit 2.

You can run `npm outdated` in your project to see if there are more outdated packages that might interfere with the new sveltekit version.